# Changing access modifiers workaround

Tags: c#

I'm fairly new to C# so forgive me if this is a stupid question. I'm experiencing an error but I do not know how to resolve it. I'm using Visual Studio 2010. I've already implemented several fixes from community members but problems seem to keep arising.

It started with this code line

```
public class GClass1 : KeyedCollection<string, GClass2>
```

I gave me the error

```
'GClass1' does not implement inherited abstract member 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection<string,GClass2>.GetKeyForItem(GClass2)'
```

From what I've read this coul be resolved by implementing the abstract member in the inherited class like so

```
public class GClass1 : KeyedCollection<string, GClass2>
{
  public override TKey GetKeyForItem(TItem item);
  protected override void InsertItem(int index, TItem item)
  {
    TKey keyForItem = this.GetKeyForItem(item);
    if (keyForItem != null)
    {
        this.AddKey(keyForItem, item);
    }
    base.InsertItem(index, item);
}
```

However that gave me errors saying 'The type or namespace name could not be found TKey/TItem could not be found.' So I replaced the placeholder types.

Currently the code is

```
public class GClass1 : KeyedCollection<string, GClass2>
{

  public override string GetKeyForItem(GClass2 item);
  protected override void InsertItem(int index, GClass2 item)
  {
    string keyForItem = this.GetKeyForItem(item);
    if (keyForItem != null)
    {
      this.AddKey(keyForItem, item);
    }
  base.InsertItem(index, item);
 }
```

I totally forgot that GetKeyForItem is protected. The new error tells me that I can't change access modifiers when overriding System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection.GetKeyForItem(GCl‌​ass2).

I am also getting a strange error saying 'GClass1.GetKeyForItem(GClass2)' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial'

Are there any workarounds to the access modifier problem, and could someone explain the 'declare a body because it is not marked' error?

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest reading a good book on C# and starting again. As you've already experienced yourself, these quick fixes will only lead to more problems.

Answer (score 2):

[`GetKeyForItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132454.aspx) is protected in the base abstract class, so it has to be protected in your derived class.  (Also, I suppose you will want to implement it -- that's the source of your second error, because methods have to have a body unless they are abstract.)

This should compile:

```
protected override string GetKeyForItem(GClass2 item)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();

    // to implement, you'd write "return item.SomePropertyOfGClass2;"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement the abstract method exactly as it's defined.  If you want that method to be publicly accessible, instead of having just the `protected` accessibility it has defined, you'll need to add a new, separate, method that uses it:

```
public class GClass1 : KeyedCollection<string, GClass2>
{
    protected override string GetKeyForItem(GClass2 item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public string GetKey(GClass2 item)
    {
        return GetKeyForItem(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error `'GClass1.GetKeyForItem(GClass2)' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial'` probably means that you need to *implement* the method, not simply declare it inside your class. In fact, you need to add a block of code to it

```
protected override string GetKeyForItem(GClass2 item)
{
     // some code
}
```

even if it does nothing.